# discordjs error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I run this snippet

```
bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let guildChannels = newMember.guild.channels;
    if(oldMember.status !== newMember.status){
        console.log(`${newMember.user.username} is now ${newMember.presence.status}`);
                guildChannels.find('name','test')
                .send(`${newMember.user.username} is now ${newMember.presence.status}`)
    }
});
```

when running this snippet (supposed to log in console as well as send messages to channel "test") it gives this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

the error is on this line

```
    if(oldMember.status !== newMember.status){
```

here is the full error log

```
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dillon\Desktop\test\test.js:18:18)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at PresenceUpdateAction.handle (C:\Users\Dillon\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\PresenceUpdate.js:39:19)
    at Object.module.exports [as PRESENCE_UPDATE] (C:\Users\Dillon\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\PRESENCE_UPDATE.js:4:33)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Dillon\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Dillon\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Dillon\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Dillon\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Dillon\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

Comment: Are you accessing those properties correctly? Print to console `oldMember` and `newMember` before that line and see what it gives you. One of them is probably going to be `undefined` as the error says.

Comment: looks like oldmember is undefined but newmember is not.

Comment: I'm not familiar with discord.js but that appears to be the correct format as noted in the docs. Is it supposed to be `undefined` in certain cases?

Comment: I'm not quite sure myself.

Comment: why you need to compare status when presence update... not make sense because only fire when the status is distinct

Comment: not sure what you mean removing the comparison still has an error occur when i try to print to the channel 'test' the status update.

Answer (score 0):

First off all use newPresence and oldPresence
Second. Its NewPresence.activities to get an array of the updates activities.
so ur codde would look like

````js
bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    let guildChannels = newMember.guild.channels;
    if(oldPresence.activities !== newMember.activities){
        console.log(`I dont know what u are trying to do.. You can try to get the the stuffs from the array by doing ${newPresence.activities[0].<PROPERTY>}`);
                guildChannels.find('name','test')
                .send(`${newPresence.username} is now ${newPresence.activities[0].<PROPERTY>}`)
    }```
});
````